# Is leaving out the word Void the same as including Void?

Tags: c#

Are these the same?

`public void MyMethod() {do something}`

`public MyMethod() {do something}`

`void` means return nothing - so leaving this key word out also means return nothing? If this is the case then why does the word exist in the language - is it used in other situations?

Comment: Readability and maintainability.

Comment: void is mandatory, if not, you read the method as constructor. The scond won't compile because you can't have it whithin class MyMethod

Comment: What's the difference between an apple and an asdfg ?

Comment: In C++, leaving the void would have meant int. But C# makes it mandatory except for Constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second option doesn't compile.

C# specs requires that every method returns a type also when there is no result to return.

> Methods are declared within a class or struct by specifying the access level, 
>       **the return value**, the name of the method, and any method parameters. ...

As noted by others the exception are class constructors.

[Methods (C# Programming Guide) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 nice one...funnily enough the chapter I'm currently on is introducing constructors - so this all now makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

You always must specify a return type for your methods regardless that its void or a type. Exceptions include constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do the second case in `C#`, it wil not compile. 
In `C#`, you should **always** specify esplicitly return type, even if it's "nothing".

Answer (score 1):

Think of `void` being a placeholder for no return value, while keeping the syntax compatible to functions/methods with a return type.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is a `public` instance *method*. It can only occur inside a `class` (or `struct`) that is **not** c itself called `MyMethod`.

The second example is a `public` instance *constructor*. It can occur inside a `class` which is itself called `MyMethod` (a strange name for a class, though).

Comment: `a strange name for a class, though).` not strange just my confusion!